# Getting matches from XRegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Using [XRegExp](https://xregexp.com/plugins/) I have the following regex to match words that start with uppercase letters:

```
var regex = XRegExp("/\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}+\p{Ll}*/gu");
var matches = XRegExp.exec("TestString", regex);
```

However the matches variable is always null. I am not sure if the regex is wrong or if I am using xregexp incorrectly. How can I get matches for words that start with uppercase letters?

Comment: Try it like this `XRegExp('\\p{Ll}*\\p{Lu}+\\p{Ll}*', 'gu');`

Comment: Try: `XRegExp("\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*", 'gu');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the examples in the [documentation](https://xregexp.com/api/), you can double escape the backslash and the flags is the second parameter.

```
XRegExp(pattern, [flags])
```

The value of pattern can be `{String|RegExp}` so you could use it like this using `String`

```js
var regex = XRegExp("\\p{Ll}*\\p{Lu}+\\p{Ll}*", "gu");
var matches = XRegExp.match("TestString", regex);
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Or use it like this using a `RegExp`

```js
var regex = XRegExp(/\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}+\p{Ll}*/gu);
var matches = XRegExp.match("TestString", regex);
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @TheFourthBird do you know how I can allow matching words with numbers as well in the regex? So basically the same thing except allowing numbers in the words. Thanks

Comment: @doorman If you want to match digits 0-9 `[\p{Ll}0-9]*\p{Lu}+[\p{Ll}0-9]*` or `[\p{Ll}\p{N}]*\p{Lu}+[\p{Ll}\p{N}]*` to match any numeric character.

Comment: Mind that `var regex = XRegExp(/\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}+\p{Ll}*/gu);` will fail in any environment that does not support ECMAScript 2018+ because the regex literal will trigger native JS regex compilation. There is no point using `u` in `var regex = XRegExp("\\p{Ll}*\\p{Lu}+\\p{Ll}*", "gu");`, as `XRegExp` was developed to address Unicode regex issues, it is not necessary here to match Unicode property classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XRegExp.match` with the `scope` set to *all*/`g` modifer, or run `XRegExp.exec` in a loop:

```js
var regex = XRegExp("\\p{Ll}*\\p{Lu}+\\p{Ll}*");
// Or: const regex = XRegExp(String.raw`\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}+\p{Ll}*`); 
var matches = XRegExp.match("TestString", regex, "all");
console.log(matches);

var regex1 = XRegExp("\\p{Ll}*\\p{Lu}+\\p{Ll}*", "g");
var results=[], match;
XRegExp.forEach("TestString", regex1, function (match, i) {
    results.push(match[0]);
});
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE**:

- Double the backslashes, or use `String.raw` notation with single backslashes in the string literal
- Do not use regex delimiters when defining the `XRegExp` patterns defined with string literals
- `u` modifier does not make sense here, unless you want to support ES6 regex features like `\u{XXXX}` and `.` matching any Unicode code point
- `g` can be overridden with `all` as the `scope` value.

See [`XRegExp.match(str, regex, [scope])`](https://xregexp.com/api/#match):

> Returns the first matched string, or in global mode, an array containing all matched strings. This is essentially a more convenient re-implementation of `String.prototype.match` that gives the result types you actually want (string instead of exec-style array in match-first mode, and an empty array instead of `null` when no matches are found in match-all mode). It also lets you override flag `g` and ignore `lastIndex`, and fixes browser bugs.

And its `scope` parameter:

> Use 'one' to return the first match as a string. Use 'all' to return an array of all matched strings. If not explicitly specified and regex uses flag `g`, scope is `all`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribizew for your answer